# How to set action column as last column in material ui table ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

[image: Material Table]

I want to set the action column as the last column .Here is my code:

```
<MaterialTable
  title="Patient List"
  columns={state.columns}
  data={data}
  onRowClick={(event, rowData) => handleCLickRow(event, rowData)}
  editable={{}),
 />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `actionsColumnIndex` that can be passed with `options` object.

The full list of props can be found here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

Comment: No it has no actions column in the array. By default the action column shows as the first column , I need to override the settings.

Answer (score 2):

`options={{actionsColumnIndex: -1}}`

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions

Answer (score 0):

```
initialState={{
  columnOrder: [
    'mrt-row-numbers',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'city',
    'mrt-row-actions' // ***
  ]
}}
```

Try this. It works fine.